# How to remove the line in my model?

Tags: modeling, normals, mirror, mirror-modifier

There's a line that runs in the middle of the snake's head. I applied the mirror modifier and I believe the line appeared. Any idea of how to remove it?
[image]

File: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5328e0201901cf1e4dcd51b6814406b120230807182007/c4b958f13b33005b9770c630a957990720230807182043/b47cd2

I've unplugged the normal map like the answers suggest but when I bake from my high poly model the line reappears.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It's because of the image you're using as normal map, it's completely black, you need to unplug the Normal Map node, or use another image

Comment: Hi moonboots, thanks for your response. I did unplug the normal and used a new normal. When I bake the details from the high poly to low the line reappears. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6cb6fa04286e026813b3a07ff323f27c20230807200722/39865eea258b5b85630f37b3c7a4310220230807200739/f38462 Thanks

Comment: switch the Image Texture from sRGB to Non-Color

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the image you're using as normal map, it's completely black, you need to unplug the *Normal Map* node, or use another image. If so, make sure that the *Image Texture* is set to *Non-Color* instead of *sRGB*.

Comment: Awesome! Both answers were correct.

Answer (score 2):

just unplug the normal map in your shader

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. I did unplug the normal and created a new one. When I bake the details from the high poly to low the line reappears. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6cb6fa04286e026813b3a07ff323f27c20230807200722/39865eea258b5b85630f37b3c7a4310220230807200739/f38462 Thanks